# Linq query problem for Take

Tags: asp.net, linq

How can I change this linq query for ust_kategori_id == 96  Take(2) and ust_kategori_id == 95 Take(2).. not Take(4)

```
var icerikler = (from icerik in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
             where icerik.ust_kategori_id == 96
             select icerik).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID).Take(4);

        repeaterListImages.DataSource = icerikler.ToList();
        repeaterListImages.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
var icerikler1 = (from icerik in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
             where icerik.ust_kategori_id == 96
             select icerik).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID).Take(2);
var icerikler2 = (from icerik in data.Tbl_Iceriklers
             where icerik.ust_kategori_id == 95
             select icerik).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID).Take(2);

var icerikler = icerikler1.Union(icerikler2).OrderByDescending(a=>a.ID);
```